# Nest.js TypeORM connect to local database (on docker container)

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, nestjs, typeorm

I have local MySQL database created in docker container from following docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  mysql:
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=changeme
      - MYSQL_USER=dbuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=changeme
    command:
      - --table_definition_cache=100
      - --performance_schema=0
      - --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
      - --innodb_use_native_aio=0
    volumes:
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    container_name: mysqldb
    image: mysql
```

And it's working fine - I can enter docker container, log in as root user (or dbuser) and create databases, tables, execute queries, etc. I also have Nest.js application which uses `@nestjs/typeorm` module to connect to database using following ormconfig.json:

```
{
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3306,
  "username": "dbuser",
  "password": "changeme",
  "database": "test",
  "synchronize": true,
  "entiries": ["src/**/*/entity.ts"]
}
```

And here is the problem - when I start application I get following error:

```
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'172.22.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

It seems that all data in ormconfig.json are correct - why my application can't connect to database?

Comment: Did you expose you ports in the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: I think that 3306 is default port, otherwise I'd get connection refused error, not access denied for user. docker ps also shows under ports 3306/tcp, 33060/tcp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have the port bound to your localhost.

**Quick and dirty solution:**
Add the following to your `mysql` service in the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
```

**More complete solution**
Move your NestJS app into your `docker-compose.yml` too.

1. Create `dev.Dockerfile` in your folder with something like this inside:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /srv/app

CMD npm run start:dev
```

2. Add your app to `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dev.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/srv/app
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: "mysql"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

If you go this way, your app will access MySQL instance through the Docker Compose network, without the need to bind MySQL port to your localhost.
It will still give nice DX as you will have hot reloading in this setup.

I hope it helps. In case of issues, feel free to comment and I will explain/edit.

Comment: I'm still getting error `api_1    | [Nest] 30  - 10/29/2021, 10:54:45 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
api_1    | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306` - I did exactly what you wrote i prefered answer (first answer didn't worked out actually, still got access denied for user error)

Comment: Ok finally got it - thanks for good answer, but there is one little detail to add. I had wrong host on my ormconfig.json, hostname should be docker generated container hostname (available under "names" on docker ps). Once I changed that it works like charm.